# How to grep before line in AIX servers

Tags: bash, shell, aix

Sample data

```
commit 3866ef2ff766054a188475ff100eeea
Author: user1
Date:   Fri Nov 1 12:41:39 2019 +0000

    JIRA-31326
    Update pbr-support-3-col-title-links.jsp

commit a976d88e8e1d8f1489a93df3b65de77a72
Author: user2
Date:   Fri Nov 1 12:33:18 2019 +0000

    JIRA-31326
    Update pbr-coveo-search.jsp

commit 04130086cadd5e552a9b327860720b2637bf
Author: user1
Date:   Fri Nov 1 12:26:24 2019 +0000

    JIRA-31327
    Update pbr-company-article-hero.jsp
```

I want to grep the Jira Id and find the commit Id for the respective grep. It is much simpler in Linux

```
git log | grep 32468 -B4 | awk '{print $2}'
```

But unfortunately -B switch is not supported in AIX for grep.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`--grep`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt) option and [`--format=%H`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt) to print the commit hash:

```sh
git log --grep 'JIRA-32468' --format=%H
```

Comment: Is there a way to grep only JIRA- and not JIRA-12456

Comment: Perhaps `git log --grep 'JIRA-'`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like with `awk` can do the work:

```
awk '/commit/{a=$2} $1 ~ "JIRA" {split($0,b,"-"); print a,b[2]}' input_file
```